# Excel Chart doesnt show/missing in existing template when using ClosedXML after exporting

Tags: c#, closedxml

Excel Chart doesnt show/missing in existing template when using ClosedXML after exporting.

Everytime I Export to the existing excel file with chart, the chart will disappear. I don't know why.

Please give me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently charts are not supported in ClosedXML according to [this issue](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/110) on github.

Comment: is there any alternative way or any third party to use to show chart in excel? Do you know some?